# web2py insert on duplicate key update

Tags: python, web2py

How to use DAL in web2py to perform INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
I have not found it in the [manual](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#insert).

Answer (score 1):

Try [`db(...).update_or_insert(...)`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#update_or_insert).

Comment: thanks but it supports only ONE key, you cannot use two fields as a key. This is definition from gluon.dal : `def update_or_insert(self, _key=DEFAULT, **values)`

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple fields as a key -- just specify `_key` as a dictionary.

Comment: yes, you are right. Could you give an example how to construct dictionary.

Comment: Also, it is possible to use any query as `_key` which I do now. In case of using dictionary what are keys in it. I tried various options but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing right now as a work around.

First I do update:

```
count = db(...).update(...)
```

it returns number of modified rows.

Then, if `count==0` then I do `insert`.